DataTimePicker - Bootstrap 4
I'm developing a tool in nodejs and I'm using bootstrap 4. And I need to format the DataTimePicker like this:
Friday, May 24, 2024.
Is it possible to change and format it in the way I indicated? Thank you in advance for your attention.

share the code so we can help you

Hey guys!
I got this code here and it helped me a lot to reach my goal.
Thank you all!




